# Python time difference from string

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a string '16:40' and I would like to calculate the difference in minutes between this string and now. So assuming *now* is 16:52, then the difference would be 12 minutes.

I have the following code:

```
import time

tString = '16:40'
t1 = time.strptime(tString, "%H:%M")
now = time.time()
print (now - t1)
```

For which get the following type error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'time.struct_time'
```

So I'm creating the incorrect type for *now* - any ideas?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to use datetime so you can do that, it's a bit different and after you have to format the date/time in the desired format but it works:

```
import datetime
tString = '16:40'
now=datetime.datetime.now()

difference=now- datetime.timedelta(hours=int(tString [:2]),minutes=int(tString [3:]))
```

Comment: and to get the minutes I use `difference.minute`.